# spotfire input handler for table only shows "None"

Tags: spotfire, terr

I registered a trivial data function with one input and one output.

`output <- input`

If I set input type to "Value" then when I go to run the function and select inputs/ouputs, under "Input Handler" I get the normal options "Value" and "Document Property".

But if I set the input type to "Table" or "Column" then when I try to run it, under "Input Handler" I only get "None". So I can't select which table to pass in as the input!

The output handler works fine -- I can select new table, etc.

Any ideas on what could be the issue? Here's an example of someone doing the same thing and apparently not running into any problems: http://datashoptalk.com/terr-in-spotfire-passing-marked-data-through-to-another-table/

Spotfire 7.6.0

[image]

Comment: By the way, this only happens in this particular dxp file. If I create a new file and create the same exact function, it works fine. Only difference I can think of is that this one has a connection to an oracle DB. I can try to pin it down further, but hints would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out. The only tables in this instance were database tables, and apparently data functions cannot be used with DB data ([spotfire doc](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.1/doc/html/data/data_working_with_in-database_data.htm)).

I guess my next question is ... why? But that can be another topic.

Answer (score 0):

When the input is a datatable the input handler does not provide an option to select the 'Data Table' but you need to actually select 'Columns'.Then select the corresponding data table and the columns you need to pass as input. If the entire data table then select all the columns.
The post you shared ,also mentions the same in one of the screenshots (Step 16).

Comment: Thanks -- but if you look at the screenshot, I don't have the "columns" option available. Is there an earlier step I'm missing?